# Why are home appliances and other devices made to operate on dc?

Tags: ac, dc, rectifier

Why are home appliances not designed to work on ac?why cant we just stepdown the incoming 230V and design the systems to operate at low ac voltages,instead of converting ac to dc?

Comment: When you say "home appliance", what specifically are you referring to? Large ones such as washing machines, blenders, garage door motors, etc generally operate on AC.

Comment: A related question:  https://electronics.stackexchange.com/questions/179373/is-ac-or-dc-more-used-in-electronic-device-designs/179378#179378

Comment: It highly depends on the "appliance". DC is cheaper and easier to produce, and is used for most circuitry (ICs, etc). AC is used in devices with transformers and large motors, because transformers ONLY work with AC and AC motors are more efficient than DC. It highly depends on the parts in the "appliance"

Answer (score 7):

As someone mentioned, appliances which have motors in them mostly run on AC -- however appliances that contain a motor and also contain some form of electronics run on a combination of AC and DC. AC is used for the motor(s) and heating elements(s), and DC is used for the electronic controls (like the control panel of a coffee machine).  These electronics will be used to control the motors or heating elements in the appliance, using a device called a TRIAC (which allows a DC voltage to control an AC voltage).

There are some appliances that only need AC, such as a garbage disposal or simple toaster.

Electronics cannot run directly on AC, it needs to be rectified and filtered to provide a smooth DC to power the electronic circuitry within the device with a constant voltage. Many electronic circuits have several different DC voltages in the same device.

There are two kinds of circuits: digital and analog.  Digital electronics uses two states, 1 (high voltage, which is the same as the supply voltage) and 0 (low voltage, called ground).  If the power supply were AC, then the logic 1 or high state would constantly be changing, and the digital logic would no longer work.

Analog electronics includes such circuitry such as an amplifier to drive a speaker, and once again powering this circuit with AC would not work.  You would have a combination of the source material (audio input) combined with the alternating power supply voltage, and get garbage coming out of the speaker or headphones.

Comment: This unfortunately overlooks the difference between AC inductions motors vs. Universal Motors that can run on either AC or DC, along with other more specialized types.  Traditionally quiet stationary appliances have used inductions motors while loud portable ones (especially if variable speed) have used universal motors, but those are generalizations.

Answer (score 5):

As mentioned in other comments/answers: some appliances work better on DC, some better on AC.

The trick is that converting AC to DC is very easy, it requires only very few basic components and the AC to DC conversion can be done efficiently.

Converting DC to AC is much more complicated, needs more components and can be
less efficient.

Also AC can be transformed to another voltage easily by using a simple transformer.

Changing the voltage can be done with DC but it requires complicated circuits instead of a simple transformer. Also for high power this is expensive. In this case using AC makes more sense.

AC motors are more efficient and so are AC generators.
So it's AC all the way unless you need DC, then you can simply convert the AC to DC.

Comment: This needs "historically" ... AC used to be easy to convert to DC, and DC used to be difficult to convert to AC. Nowadays, with fast switching semiconductors, you need pretty much the same set of parts to convert in either direction, at similar cost...

Comment: @BrianDrummond, then please convince me by showing me an example of a DC to AC converter for less than the price of 4 diodes and an electolytic cap.

Comment: I won't. Less than the price of the above and a suitably rated 50-60Hz transformer, sure. So I'll concede that there are rare exceptions where the required DC voltage and the supplied AC voltage align, but that's not generally true.What has changed is that a tiny amount of matter (Si) has removed the dependency on a large expensive lump of matter (Fe,Cu)

Comment: @IC_designer_Rimpelbekkie: Four diodes and a cap may be a cheap and workable approach for low-demand applications, but if the current demand is too great to be concentrated in a tiny portion of the AC cycle four diodes and a cap just won't cut it.